# Cannot create an instance of my COM class with ComPtr

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, interface, com

I'm having problems creating my COM Interface.

I have it defined as the following:

```
struct __declspec( uuid( "36244c2e-4883-47cb-9e02-5d4ea3cc38d9" ) )
IMyObject : IPersist, IPropertyBag
{
    virtual void __stdcall DoObjectStuff() = 0;
};

HRESULT __stdcall CreateObject( IMyObject** myObject);
```

And the incomplete implementation:

```
struct MyObject : IMyObject
{
    // reference counter
    long m_count;

    MyObject()
        :
        m_count( 0 )
    {
        printf("Creating MyObject!\n");
    }


    // IUnknownInterface
    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef() override
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual ULONG  __stdcall Release() override
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface( REFIID riid, void** ppvObject )
    {
            ASSERT( ppvObject );

            const auto id = riid;

          if( id == __uuidof( IMyObject ) ||
              id == __uuidof( IUnknown ) ) 
          {
             *ppvObject = static_cast<IMyObject*>( this );
          }
          else if( id == __uuidof( IPropertyBag ) )
          {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IPropertyBag*>( this );
          }
          else if( id == __uuidof( IPersist ))
          {
                *ppvObject = static_cast<IPersist*>( this );
          }
          else
          {
                // unsupported interface
                 *ppvObject = nullptr;
                 return E_NOINTERFACE;
          }

         static_cast<IUnknown*>( *ppvObject )->AddRef();
         return S_OK;
    }




    // IPersist
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetClassID(CLSID* pClassID) override
    {
        // ...
    }

    // IPropertyBag
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Read( LPCOLESTR pszPropName, VARIANT* pVar, IErrorLog* pErrorLog ) override
    {
        // ...
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Write( LPCOLESTR pszPropName, VARIANT* pVar ) override
    {
           // ...
    }

    // IMyObject
    virtual void __stdcall DoObjectStuff() override
    {
        std::cout << "Object stuff is being done!" << std::endl;
    }

};

HRESULT __stdcall CreateObject( IMyObject** myObject )
{
    // creates the object
}
```

Now, both [`IPropertyBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-ipropertybag) and [`IPersist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersist) implement [`IUnknown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iunknown), do I need to explicitly derive my interface from `IUnknown` as well?

The problem I'm facing here is that when I try to create an object:

```
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
ComPtr<IMyObject> myObject;
```

I get [error C2385](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2385?view=msvc-170), what gives?

It says the problem is with the `Release()` function inside `ComPtr`.

Comment: *do I need to explicitly derive my interface from IUnknown as well?* - no. you can use `ComPtr<MyObject>` or add `virtual ULONG  __stdcall Release();` to `IMyObject` declaration

Comment: `IMyObject : IPersist, IPropertyBag` This ain't gonna work. A COM object may derive from multiple interfaces; but for COM interfaces, multiple inheritance is not supported. `IMyObject` ends up derived from `IUnknown` twice; that's going to cause problems. Most likely, you want to derive `IMyObject` from `IUnknown`, then derive `MyObject` from all three of `IMyObject`, `IPersist` and `IPropertyBag`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik wont they share the same address? I mean IPersist's implementation of Release would point to the same addresse as IPropertyBag implementation of Release. Am I wrong?

Comment: Every interface pointer must be unambiguously convertible to `IUnknown*`. And `IMyObject*` is not thus convertible.

Comment: Unrelated, your `QueryInterface` implementation is wrong. It claims that your object doesn't support `IUnknown`, which of course it must.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik alright, I think I fixed it, how's it now?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik regarding the interface I did what you said, restricted ```IMyObject``` to inheriting only ```IUnknown``` and then when creating the objecting inherited from all of them (```IMyObject```, ```IPersist```, ```IPortable```) and it worked

Comment: *"IPersist's implementation of Release would point to the same addresse as IPropertyBag implementation of Release"* - You *can* implement it that way, but there is no requirement that the addresses be the same. COM reference counting is strictly **per interface**. Derivation in COM amounts to interface reuse, which may or may not be implemented as code reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the IgorTandetnik's suggestion:

Restricted `IMyObject` to inheriting only `IUnknown` and then when creating the objecting inherited from all of them (`IMyObject`, `IPersist`, `IPortable`).